# CartesianChartModel database values

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

in the [link](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/barChart.jsf), it is shows that by hardcoding input, we can produce the chart. Now instead of setting the values for example of boys and girls, I would like to query the database, get the sum of requests with ACTIVE status. I can do that but how can I model this in the chart provided here?

Answer (score 0):

something like that?
You need to add your db query logic yourself...

```
private void createCategoryModel() {  
    categoryModel = new CartesianChartModel();  

    ChartSeries active_chart = new ChartSeries();  
    active_chart.setLabel("ACTIVE");  

    int total = 250;
    int active = 100;
    int non_active = total - active;

    active_chart.set("Bar_Lablel", active);  


    ChartSeries non_active_chart = new ChartSeries();  
    non_active_chart.setLabel("NON ACTIVE ");  

    non_active_chart.set("Bar_Lablel", non_active);  


    categoryModel.addSeries(active_chart);  
    categoryModel.addSeries(non_active_chart);  
}
```